# Checking and Killing processes of a user before deleting

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am working on a script to delete users from text file. However, before deleting, I want to check if any process by a user is running and if running then kill all the processes and delete.
Here's how I'm doing this:

```
    if 
   #user doesn't exists then print user not exist
else
pids = `ps U "$name" -o pid | head -n -1` 
    if [ -n "$pids" ]
    then
    for pid in $pids
    do
        sudo kill -KILL $pid
    done
fi


     sudo userdel

 $name -r -f    
    echo     


       echo "The user - $name - has been deleted!"
    echo
    fi
    done < "$fname"                         # double-quote fname
    echo
```

So, basically its a loop to delete users and in that an if statement to make sure no process is being run by a user and if its being run then force close processes and delete user.

However, Its not working and it says `pids: command not found`.. Any solution, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following code:

```
pids = `ps U "$name" -o pid | head -n -1`
```

bash is picky about whitespace, here. Simply remove the spaces from `pids = ...` and it will work as intended:

```
pids=`ps U "$name" -o pid | head -n -1`
```

Comment: Thank you!! Programming gets really annoying sometimes, when you make a mistake like that.. Thanks for saving my life :D

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

1) You cannot have a space around the `=` in shell script variable assignment. `pids = ...` should be `pids=...`.
2) `kill` can accept multiple PIDs. You don't need a `for pid in $pids ...` loop. (though with the next item, this is irrelevant)
3) Your code can be drastically simplified by doing:

```
pkill -KILL -U "$name"
```

There is no need to check if the user has any processes running. If there aren't any, the command does nothing.